# Why are fielddialog widgets restarting the Spyder kernel on exit?

Tags: tkinter

I’m using tkinter with python3.8 and Spyder. I’m trying to use the filedialog boxes.
The following code runs, but the kernel dies and restarts when I click (and reclick and reclick) the exit button. I have tried both Button statements, neither solve the problem. Changing to askopenfilename does not help. It runs and does what it should, but it restarts the kernal upon exit. It is also hard to exit, the button does not work and I must click the "X" in the window corner several times to exit.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
import sys
root=Tk()
#B=Button(root, text="Exit", command=root.destroy).pack()
B=Button(root, text="Exit", command=sys.exit).pack()
F=filedialog.askopenfile(mode='r', initialdir = "./data",title = "Select file",filetypes = 
(("text","*.txt"),("all files","*.*")))
print (f"F={F}")
```

The error message is:"[SpyderKernelApp] WARNING | No such comm: a20c0911fd3a11ea86ef14b31f06b0c3"

Comment: It works when using `spyder` version 5.0.0.dev and `command=root.destroy` for `B`.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the similar issue while I tried to read/ write files from Spyder.
It seems to me that I didn't have enough permission to carry out a certain operation.

So, I changed the ownership of the external drives and this fixed the issues for me. The way I did it was:

```
sudo chown yourusername:yourusername /media/yourusername/path_to_mounted_volume
```

I truly hope this will solve your issue as well.